# How to get user info after press like button

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, facebook-graph-api

I have social media toolbar. and I have facebook like button,my desire is when someone click on facebook like button than find user and store related information to my database for promotions.

I have made such

```
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

        FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(response) {
            var FBGraphURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/user/callback=?";

            FB.getLoginStatus(function(res) { alert(res); });

            FB.api('/me', function(resp) {
                alert('Good to see you, ' + resp.username + '.');
            });
        });
    };
```

But still resp.username is shown as **undefined**. how i can resolve this problem ?

**update**

Working Code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
        login();
    });
};

function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            GetUser();
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
}

function GetUser() {
    FB.api('/me', function(resp) {
        alert('Good to see you, ' + resp.email + '.');
    });
}
```

Also that each domain have to different App Id (**Important**)

Comment: You do not get _any_ information about the user, until they have connected to your app.

Comment: yaa, true but I am already login. Than also not getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The like plugin only returns you the URL on what the like was made.
To grab user informations you have to you use a fb connect, and when the user has accepted your application, you can retrieve his informations with his access token !

Look here for more details : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/